# Lock a cell in a relative position with adding rows

Tags: google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple table that is sitting on the range J4:M24. I also have another table on the range A4:H56. Is there any way I can lock the table in J4:M24 so that whenever I add new rows to the table on the left side (A4:H56), the other table will not shift down?

I basically want to tell the table on the right side that no matter what happens in terms of adding or removing rows to the one on the left, the one on the right will always be on the range J4:M24.

Is there any way that can be done? Either by a onEdit script, a function, or any preference on the Google Sheets built-in functions?

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT("J4:M24")
```

this way no matter what you do (add/remove rows/columns) it will always point to that range and also the range will not change on itself

---

in case you want to have a frozen table you will need to create a virtual table:

```
={"","","","";"","","","";"","","","";
  "xx"   ,     "cc" ,      "22" ,     "1"    ;
  "abc"  ,     123  ,      ""   ,      56    ;
  "cd"   ,     ""   ,      456  ,      ""    ;
  "hjk"  ,     99   ,      88   ,      "fff" ;
  ""     ,     ""   ,      ""   ,      ""    ;
  "etc"  ,     ""   ,      ""   ,      ""    ;
  "etc"  ,     ""   ,      ""   ,      ""    }
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, but, unless i am seeing it wrong, I don't think it is. That just references from one place to another right? What i want is the original table to stay in place. I still want to edit the cells in that range, just want to make the cells stay always in that specific range, no matter how many cells i add before it.

Comment: I see, in that case, you need to either print it with script or create a virtual table and project it from 1st row. answer updated